# I can not execute my project in emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-emulator

I am doing a simple project using google maps. My project is running fine in my mobile. But i can not run in emulator. When i try to execute the following error is showing..

```
    11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128): Process: info.android.googlemapsv2, PID: 3128
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {info.android.googlemapsv2/info.android.slidingmenu.SlideActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at com.tracker.newmaps.MainActivityNew.GetLocaion(MainActivityNew.java:210)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at com.tracker.newmaps.MainActivityNew.onResume(MainActivityNew.java:300)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1743)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1863)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5320)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
11-23 12:50:44.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3128):     ... 12 more
```

I am using `Google APIs x86(Google Inc.)` Target api, and emulator also `Google APIs x86(Google Inc.)`

Please let me know how to run the project in my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the emulator you don't have Google play services installed. [This](http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/) link could be helpful too.